# What Wordpress Hook Is Used Before Signup Data is Saved?

Tags: customization

I need hook which is working before signup data save on new user and blog registration on BP or WP 3.0.3. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This one?

`do_action( 'register_post', $sanitized_user_login, $user_email, $errors );`

http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?wp-login.php.source.html line 316

Answer (score 2):

You need to look inside the files and follow the program flow to find out about hooks and global variables to interact with.

Multi-Site Setup is a mess hook-wise, this can be pretty hacky. Some hints to far:

### Standard User Registration (Single-Site)

File: `wp-login.php`

Function: `register_new_user()`

Hooks: `register_post`, `registration_errors`

### Site Registration (Multi-Site)

File: `wp-signup.php`

Functions: `validate_another_blog_signup()`, `signup_another_blog()`

Hook: `wpmu_validate_user_signup`